# Is there an API for HP DreamColor Monitors? Something that can control input via internal USB hub?

Tags: usb, external-display, input-device, hid

I have a HP DreamColor Z24x G2 monitor and a couple of HP Z24N monitors (first edition I believe) and both models have a built-in USB hub.

Interestingly, on the HP DreamColor Z24x G2, the USB 2.0 HUB device also reveals a USB HID device with an HP vendor ID.

Seeing that got me wondering what that device does and if there is a way to control various elements of the monitor from the host computer over USB?

Automated or hot-key 'Input switching' in particular would be a great value add for these units!

> [image]

```
HID USB DESCRIPTOR DUMP
----------
0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,  // Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF00)
0x09, 0x01,        // Usage (0x01)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x19, 0x01,        //   Usage Minimum (0x01)
0x29, 0x40,        //   Usage Maximum (0x40)
0x15, 0x01,        //   Logical Minimum (1)
0x25, 0x40,        //   Logical Maximum (64)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x40,        //   Report Count (64)
0x81, 0x00,        //   Input (Data,Array,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x19, 0x01,        //   Usage Minimum (0x01)
0x29, 0x40,        //   Usage Maximum (0x40)
0x91, 0x00,        //   Output (Data,Array,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              // End Collection
// 28 bytes
```

Comment: Does this appear without any other device connected to it? HID typically means keyboard, mouse and few others...

Comment: Yes, that HID device shows up with nothing else plugged in. I got an HID report descriptor and I'm about to paste it to the original question.

Comment: +1 and I'll keep an eye on this. I'm now as curious as you.

Comment: I should also add that the Z24n does NOT have this HID device. Only the Z24x. Also, the 'x' model supports saving color correction settings in the monitor when calibrating with an x-rite or similar calibrator. I have ignorance about how this works but wonder if the calibration device software interacts with the monitor through this HID device.

Comment: I tried a few quick searches of the USB product and vendor ID shown in your screen grab to find out what the device might be and found nothing helpful.  That doesn't mean that information is not available, only that I might not have searched hard enough, perhaps you would have better success with the right keywords in a search.  I also suspect this is how the display communicates to the attached computer, likely for things like calibrating color or such.  My point is that the USB vendor and product ID should be enough to found out what the device is and deduce its function.

Comment: @MacGuffin My thoughts exactly. And I did the same and found nothing.